# Is my brake disk warped?

Tags: brake-rotor

I've been hearing an annoying rubbing noise from front right wheel since replacing the front brake pads. I drive my car only occasionally, maybe 1000 km in 2+ months, so I can't say I've driven enough for the new pads to get bedded. To make sure that the noise was indeed coming from the pad contacting the disk I jacked up the car and rotated the wheel and verified that the pads were really contacting the disk surface. The noise was the same. Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is it normal that brake pads are in contact with the brake disk even when the brake pedal is not pressed? I thought the rotor should be able to rotate freely when no braking is applied.
2. And the main concern: When I rotate the wheel I can see that it rotates easily for the 90% of the circle, but it gets hard at the rest 10%. So this makes me think that the disk is warped and that's what makes the noise? Am I correct in my suspicion?

Comment: Did you get the rotors resurfaced when you put the new pads on?

Comment: Ummm, no, they didn't do anything besides just cleaning the area with WD40. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

WD-40 is not brake cleaner.  I would take it apart and clean it with the appropriate stuff.  Also can you move your caliper back and forth?  It should be able to "float" or slide back and forth a little on the pins.  If it's not moving, you could have a pad that's dragging and making constant contact (as well as noise) on the rotor.

Comment: I'll give it a try this evening